# One page horizontal scrolling website - not able to highlight current link on navbar

Tags: jquery, css

I am designing a website for my college fest. This is a one-page horizontal scrolling website. I want to know how to highlight the current link on the nav-bar. This may look like a repeat question, but none of the existing answers have helped me.

This is what my code looks like.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <nav id="menubar">
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"/></div>
        <div id="bar">
            <span class="fest"><a href="#home">Home</a></span>
            <span class="fest"><a href="#aboutUs">About Us</a></span>
            <span class="fest"><a href="#events">Events</a></span>
            <span class="fest"><a href="#schedule">Schedule</a></span>
            <span class="fest"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></span>                
            <span class="fest"><a href="#people">People</a></span>
            <span class="fest"><a href="#sponsors">Sponsors</a></span>
            <span class="fest"><a href="#reachUs">Reach Us</a></span>               
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="home"></section>
    <section id="aboutUs"></section>
    <section id="events"></section>
    //more
</div>
```

CSS: (only the relevant ones)

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 800%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
}

#bar .fest a {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.5vw;   
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
var aChildren = $("#bar .fest").children();
var aArray = [];
for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
    var aChild = aChildren[i];
    var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
    aArray.push(ahref);
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollLeft();
    for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
        var theID = aArray[i];
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().left;
        var divWidth = $(theID).width();
        if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divWidth)) {
            $("#bar .fest a[href='"+theID+"']").css("color","red");
        } else {
            $("#bar .fest a[href='"+theID+"']").css("color","black");
        }
    }
});
```

This is the code I picked up from various sources (it does not work). What is the mistake? Does it have something to do with the fact that I am scrolling in the #container div and not the body?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Have you considered using fullPage.js?

Comment: Could you please expound on that @Alvaro?

Comment: @goto My problem is that this code, although seemingly correct, is not producing the desired effect i.e. highlighting the respective links in the navbar based on horizontal scroll position. I don't know the specific error (I did think it was something to do with the #container scrolling). This was the shortest code I could reduce it to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sHKsL/3/

Comment: @vel Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. But could you tell me what is wrong with my code? And whether body or #container scrolling is better?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vkeboz1y/1/. check this. menu like fixed ans section scrooling better

Comment: http://patik.com/code/within-viewport/

Comment: I tried the above method on my code @vel. It did not work. My sections have responsive width. How do I give vw values for scrollLeft?

Comment: @Quasar you can check [fullPage.js demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). You can easily use a single section with plently of slies. And even use the [Scroll Horizontally extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scrollHorizontally.html) if you want to use the wheel too. You can also use methods and callbacks to link it with your menu.

Comment: I am also using the ScrollMagic Library. Would this not hinder it a=in any way? @Alvaro

Comment: @Quasar probably not. fullPage.js uses the scrollLeft property for the horizontal sliders when using `css3:false`.In any case, you should maybe consider using the [fullPage.js state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) or [callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) to fire those animations.

Comment: My code was proper. It was something to do with the placement of my <script> tags. I still don't know why the order matters or why it matters if they are in <head> or <body>. Thank you vel and alvaro for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
            var topMenu = $("#bar"),
            topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
            // All list items
            menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
            // Anchors corresponding to menu items
            scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
              var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
              if (item.length) { return item; }
            });

        // Bind to scroll
        $(window).scroll(function(){
           // Get container scroll position
           var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

           // Get id of current scroll item
           var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
             if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
               return this;
           });
           // Get the id of the current element
           cur = cur[cur.length-1];
           var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
           // Set/remove active class
           menuItems
             .parent().removeClass("active")
             .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
        });
```

Comment: This is a horizontal scrolling page